# pandas: how to find the most frequent value of each row?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

how to find the most frequent value of each row of a dataframe?
For example:

```
In [14]: df
Out[14]:
   a  b  c
0  2  3  3
1  1  1  2
2  7  7  8
```

return:
    [3,1,7]

Answer (score 29, accepted):

try [.mode()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mode.html) method:

```
In [88]: df
Out[88]:
   a  b  c
0  2  3  3
1  1  1  2
2  7  7  8

In [89]: df.mode(axis=1)
Out[89]:
   0
0  3
1  1
2  7
```

From docs:

> Gets the mode(s) of each element along the axis selected. Adds a row
>   for each mode per label, fills in gaps with nan.
>
> **Note** that there could be multiple values returned for the selected
>   axis (when more than one item share the maximum frequency), which is
>   the reason why a dataframe is returned. If you want to impute missing
>   values with the mode in a dataframe df, you can just do this:
>   df.fillna(df.mode().iloc[0])