# python - how to iterate each row and set the most often appears

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a 'dataframe' which has 3 columns, and I need to fill the fourth column, explained below

```
df['question'] = ''
df.head()
>> output
v1                  v2                  v3           question
A                   A                   B            
C                   D                   D
```

so I want to fill the 'question' column with the result of the 'string' that appears most often for each line, if the 'string' appears more than once then this is the one I will use to fill the column, example of what can happen:

```
v1                  v2                  v3           question
A                   A                   B            A
C                   D                   D            D  
E                   F                   E            E
```

Comment: Check this out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36091902/pandas-how-to-find-the-most-frequent-value-of-each-row

Comment: `df['question'] = df.filter(regex='^v').mode(1)[0]`

Comment: thanks! but your code didn't work, it returned an error, so I went to the link you indicated and did the following

`df['question'] = df.mode(axis=1)` 

And it worked!!